# Bootstrap 3 Tabs, firefox autofocus not working

Tags: javascript, twitter-bootstrap, firefox

I am using bootstrap 3 tabs. To directly jump to a specific tab, I use the following code:

```
function tabNavigation() {
    if (location.hash.indexOf("#tab_") == 0 && $('a[href="' + location.hash + '"]').length) {
      var $d = $('a[href="' + location.hash + '"]');
    }
    else {
      $d = $(".tabnavigation a:first");
    }
    $d.tab('show');
    $(location.hash + " [autofocus]").first().focus();
  }

  window.addEventListener("hashchange", tabNavigation, false);
  tabNavigation();
  $("body").on("click", ".tabnavigation a", function () {
    window.location.hash = $(this).attr("href").substr(1);
  });
});
```

This works as expected. The problem now is, that if there is an autofocus attribute on one of the tabs, it doesn't work in Firefox (but it works in Chrome).

```
<input class="form-control" autofocus id="input2" required="required" name="input2" type="text">
```

I have also tried to do it with js:

```
$("[autofocus]").first().focus();
```

Have a look at bootplay (works in Chrome, but not in Firefox):

http://www.bootply.com/iN1e0QTVif

but this works neither. Any ideas?

Comment: try `autofocus="true"` in your code

Comment: no, its not working. you can try it on bootply

Comment: Actually, this is currently working on bootplay link provided (with Firefox 82)

Answer (score 0):

> [Only one form element in a document can have the `autofocus` attribute](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/Input#attr-autofocus)

You have multiple `<input>`s with the `autofocus` attribute, so your document isn't valid HTML.